# Xcode build the same project for simulator failed but build for device success

Tags: ios, xcode

Whether it is simulator or device, Build app was successful two weeks ago, but yesterday I rebuilt the app and it failed in simulator mode, but it still succeeded in device mode.

build failed image:

[image: build failed image]

error detail 1:

[image: error detail 1]

error detail 2:

[image: error detail 2]

successful image:

[image: successful image]

I tried to find the difference between the two, but I couldn't find it. I also tried to use different simulator models (ex. iphonex) but also got the same result.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you clear DerivedData?

Comment: Or you might have to reinstall pods.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.